# Uneven Sorting in DataTable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables-1.10

My HTML is like below.

```
<table id="address_datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
       <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Company Name</th>
         <th>Contact Name</th>
         <th>Email Address</th>
         <th>Phone Number</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
 <tbody>
```

My jQuery code is like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#address_datatable').DataTable({
                "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": [ 0, 2 ],
                "orderable": false
                } ]
            });
   });
```

2 is working in `"targets"` but 0 is not working.

I tried below example also. It is not working

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 'nosort',
      "orderable": false
    } ]
} );
```

Why it is happening like this ?

Answer (score 1):

try this way

in HTML

```
<table id="address_datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
       <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Company Name</th>
         <th>Contact Name</th>
         <th>Email Address</th>
         <th>Phone Number</th>
         <th class="nosort">Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
 <tbody>
```

in JS

```
 $('#address_datatable').dataTable( {
      "columnDefs": [ {
          "targets": 'nosort',
          "orderable": false
        } ]
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add more details to your question..
Are you using ajax data source or simple static table data?

If ajax do the following.

```
ajax:{
type:'post', // whatever method
url:"your url"
},
  "columns": [
//Specify your columns here
 ],
columnDefs:[
//Column definitions here
]
} );
```

Comment: Thanks @Navaneth Raman Bhaskar. But 2 is working here `"targets": [ 0, 2 ],`. Thanks.

Comment: I am using Simple Static Table.

Comment: @abuabu
see this documentation 
https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data

Comment: **Conflict resolution**
check for conflicts: 

1.A property defined in columns will always take priority over any value for that property defined in columnDefs.
2.Properties which are higher in the columnDefs array will take priority over those below.